# Python write output separated by semi-colon

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to output fields to a text file. I've been able to throw the output to a text file but it's got "[" and "]" bracketing each row and is separated by commas.

I don't want the enclosing brackets and I have a date field that contains a comma so I need the fields to be separated by semi-colons.

Here's an example of the code that I'm using:

```
f=open("output.txt","a+")

for item in x['data']:
    print "Variable 1: " + str(var1) 
    print "Variable 2: " + str(var2)

    a=str(var1.strip())
    b=str(var2.strip())

    row = "%s\n" % [a,b] 

f.write(row)
```

My output looks like this:

```
['var1', 'var2']
```

I want it to look like this:

```
'var1'; 'var2'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `';'.join([a,b])`?

Comment: Explanation of your undesired result: your current `row` line *forces* Python to use its `__str__`  (or possibly `__repr__`, I always confuse these two) function on a list.

Comment: Actually, this is also very helpful. The only thing it does that I don't know how to fix is it strips all the control characters out of a variable that I want to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them wrapped in single quotes, `'var1'; 'var2'`, then use any of

```
row = "; ".join(repr(x) for x in [a, b])
```

or

```
row = "%r; %r" % (a, b)
```

or

```
row = "{!r}; {!r}".format(a, b)
```

Comment: The first one gets me the closest - the only problem is it puts all of the data on one row with out a newline to separate the rows. Adding \n results in all of the fields on separate rows. The second results in "not all arguments converted during string formatting". And the third doesn't give me an error but I'm missing data and everything is all on the same row like the first example.

Comment: @Steve The `.write` of a file object does not magically add new lines, you need to handle that yourself, or alternatively use `print >> f, row`.  The second alternative works as advertised, make sure you are using `(a, b)` not `[a, b]`